# How to make username and logout button appear after logging in

Tags: php

I am currently using Drmweaver trying to make the username and logout button appears after logging in and I tried using Recordset in order to make the username appears but failed. I also tried the coding suggested in an ask before this but after I log in, it still shows the login button, but the username and logout didn't appear. This is the coding suggested ( thank you netsmertia!) i've been trying on.

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['admin_id'])){
        echo "you logged in as </br>", $_SESSION['admin_id'];
        echo "<br/><a href='logout.php'>logout</a>";
    }else{
    echo '<a href="login.php"> LOgin </a>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: what is your `print_r($_SESSION)`? If it's empty then obviously u are not setting session variables and the time of log in.

Comment: Can you include your login script in the code so we can check it out? That is what would be wrong...

Comment: What is probably not happening correctly is the login.php page is not correctly setting the session or session variable

Comment: @Wyy can you show your code to set the value

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to safe the username and the status of the session in the php function that logs the user in.

Something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

function log_in($username, $password) {
   //check user data....
   $_SESSION['status']   = 'loggedin';
   $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $username;
}

//some code........

if($_SESSION['status'] == 'loggedin') {
   echo "You're logged in as ".$_SESSION['admin_id'].".<br/>";
   echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
} else {
   echo '<a href="login.php">Login</a>';
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `echo "You're logged in as ".$_SESSION['admin_id'];` saves you a keystroke ;)